Problema al actualizar el nombre del proveedor en React: aparece como 'N/A' hasta que se recarga la página
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en React donde gestiono productos y proveedores. El problema surge cuando intento actualizar un producto. El nombre del proveedor se carga correctamente al editar el producto, pero al intentar actualizarlo, el nombre del proveedor aparece como "N/A" hasta que recargo la página.
He revisado el código y parece que el nombre del proveedor solo se actualiza correctamente en la vista después de la recarga de la página. El código para manejar el formulario de actualización de productos está en el siguiente componente:
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import axios from "axios";
    import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
    import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf';
    import autoTable from 'jspdf-autotable';
    import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
    
    const GestionInventario = () => {
      const [Productos, setProductos] = useState([]);
      const [proveedores, setProveedores] = useState([]);
      const [nombre, setNombre] = useState("");
      const [cantidad, setCantidad] = useState("");
      const [precio, setPrecio] = useState("");
      const [proveedorId, setProveedorId] = useState("");
      const [imagen, setImagen] = useState(null);
      const [editId, setEditId] = useState(null);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
          try {
            const ProductosResponse = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/Productos");
            const proveedoresResponse = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/proveedores");
            setProductos(ProductosResponse.data);
            setProveedores(proveedoresResponse.data);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error al cargar los datos", error);
          }
        };
        fetchData();
      }, []);
    
      const handleImageChange = (e) => {
        setImagen(e.target.files[0]);
      };
    
      const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("nombre", nombre);
        formData.append("cantidad", cantidad);
        formData.append("precio", precio);
        formData.append("proveedorId", proveedorId);
        if (imagen) {
          formData.append("imagen", imagen);
        }
    try {
      if (editId) {
        const response = await axios.put(
          `http://localhost:5000/api/Productos/${editId}`,
          formData,
          { headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" } }
        );
        const updatedProducto = {
          ...response.data,
          Proveedor: proveedores.find((prov) => prov.id === response.data.Proveedor),
        };
        setProductos(Productos.map((Producto) =>
          Producto.id === editId ? updatedProducto : Producto
        ));
      } else {
        const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/Productos", formData, {
          headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
        });
        const Proveedor = proveedores.find((prov) => prov.id === parseInt(proveedorId));
        setProductos([...Productos, { ...response.data, Proveedor: Proveedor }]);
      }
      resetForm();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error al gestionar el Producto", error);
    }
  };
  const handleUpdateProveedor = async (proveedor) => {
    // Primero, actualizamos el proveedor
    await axios.put(`http://localhost:5000/api/proveedores/${proveedor.id}`, proveedor);
  
    // Si el proveedor ha sido actualizado, también debemos actualizar los productos asociados
    const productosAsociados = Productos.filter((producto) => producto.proveedorId === proveedor.id);
    
    for (let producto of productosAsociados) {
      await axios.put(`http://localhost:5000/api/Productos/${producto.id}`, {
        ...producto,
        proveedorId: proveedor.id, // Actualizar proveedorId si el proveedor ha cambiado
      });
    }
  
    // Luego, refrescar la lista de proveedores y productos
    const proveedoresResponse = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/proveedores");
    setProveedores(proveedoresResponse.data);
    
    const productosResponse = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/Productos");
    setProductos(productosResponse.data);
  };
  
  const handleEdit = (Producto) => {
    setEditId(Producto.id);
    setNombre(Producto.nombre);
    setCantidad(Producto.cantidad);
    setPrecio(Producto.precio);
    setProveedorId(Producto.proveedorId);
    setImagen(null);
  };

  const handleDelete = async (id) => {
    try {
      await axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/api/Productos/${id}`);
      setProductos(Productos.filter((Producto) => Producto.id !== id));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error al eliminar el Producto", error);
    }
  };

  const resetForm = () => {
    setEditId(null);
    setNombre("");
    setCantidad("");
    setPrecio("");
    setProveedorId("");
    setImagen(null);
  };

  // Formato de moneda en MX
  const formatCurrency = (value) => {
    return new Intl.NumberFormat('es-MX', {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: 'MXN',
    }).format(value);
  };

  // Exportar a Excel
  const exportToExcel = () => {
    const totalGeneral = Productos.reduce((total, producto) => {
      return total + (producto.cantidad * producto.precio);
    }, 0);

    const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(Productos.map(producto => ({
      Nombre: producto.nombre,
      Cantidad: producto.cantidad,
      Precio: producto.precio,
      Total: producto.cantidad * producto.precio, // Total por producto
      Proveedor: producto.Proveedor ? producto.Proveedor.nombre : 'N/A',
    })));

    XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(ws, [['', '', '', 'Total General', totalGeneral]], { origin: -1 });

    const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "Productos");
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, "productos.xlsx");
  };



const exportToPDF = () => {
    const doc = new jsPDF();
    const body = Productos.map(producto => [
      producto.nombre,
      producto.cantidad,
      formatCurrency(producto.precio),
      producto.Proveedor ? producto.Proveedor.nombre : 'N/A',
      formatCurrency(producto.cantidad * producto.precio), 
    ]);

    const totalGeneral = Productos.reduce((total, producto) => {
      return total + (producto.cantidad * producto.precio);
    }, 0);

    autoTable(doc, {
      head: [['Nombre', 'Cantidad', 'Precio', 'Proveedor', 'Total']],
      body: body,
      foot: [['', '', '', 'Total General', formatCurrency(totalGeneral)]], 
    });
    
    doc.save("productos.pdf");
  };

  return (
    <div className="max-w-6xl mx-auto p-6 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg shadow-lg">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="bg-white p-6 rounded-lg shadow-md">
        <div className="mb-4">
          <label className="block text-gray-700 font-semibold">Nombre</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={nombre}
            onChange={(e) => setNombre(e.target.value)}
            className="w-full p-3 mt-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-500"
            required
          />
        </div>

        <div className="mb-4">
          <label className="block text-gray-700 font-semibold">Cantidad</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            value={cantidad}
            onChange={(e) => setCantidad(e.target.value)}
            className="w-full p-3 mt-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-500"
            required
          />
        </div>

        <div className="mb-4">
          <label className="block text-gray-700 font-semibold">Precio</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            value={precio}
            onChange={(e) => setPrecio(e.target.value)}
            className="w-full p-3 mt-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-500"
            required
          />
        </div>

        <div className="mb-4">
          <label className="block text-gray-700 font-semibold">Imagen</label>
          <input
            type="file"
            accept="image/*"
            onChange={handleImageChange}
            className="w-full p-3 mt-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-500"
          />
        </div>

        <div className="mb-6">
          <label className="block text-gray-700 font-semibold">Proveedor</label>
          <select
            value={proveedorId}
            onChange={(e) => setProveedorId(e.target.value)}
            className="w-full p-3 mt-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-500"
            required
          >
            <option value="">Selecciona un proveedor</option>
            {proveedores.map((prov) => (
              <option key={prov.id} value={prov.id}>
                {prov.nombre}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </div>



    <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="px-6 py-2 bg-blue-500 text-white font-semibold rounded-lg shadow-md hover:bg-blue-600"
          >
            {editId ? "Actualizar Producto" : "Crear Producto"}
          </button>
          {editId && (
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={resetForm}
              className="px-6 py-2 bg-gray-300 text-gray-700 font-semibold rounded-lg shadow-md hover:bg-gray-400"
            >
              Cancelar
            </button>
          )}
        </div>
      </form>

      <div className="mt-8 overflow-x-auto">
        <div className="flex justify-end mb-4">
          <button
            onClick={exportToPDF}
            className="bg-red-500 text-white py-2 px-4 rounded-lg flex items-center hover:font-semibold">
            <i className="fa fa-file-pdf-o mr-2"></i> Exportar a PDF
          </button>
          <button
            onClick={exportToExcel}
            className="bg-green-500 text-white py-2 px-4 rounded-lg flex items-center ml-4 hover:font-semibold">
            <i className="fa fa-file-excel-o mr-2"></i> Exportar a Excel
          </button>
        </div>
        <table className="min-w-full bg-white shadow-md rounded-lg overflow-hidden">
          <thead className="bg-gray-200">
            <tr>
              <th className="py-3 px-6 text-left">Nombre</th>
              <th className="py-3 px-6 text-left">Cantidad</th>
              <th className="py-3 px-6 text-left">Precio</th>
              <th className="py-3 px-6 text-left">Proveedor</th>
              <th className="py-3 px-6 text-left">Total</th>
              <th className="py-3 px-6 text-center">Acciones</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {Productos.map((producto) => (
              <tr key={producto.id} className="border-t">
                <td className="py-3 px-6">{producto.nombre}</td>
                <td className="py-3 px-6">{producto.cantidad}</td>
                <td className="py-3 px-6">{formatCurrency(producto.precio)}</td>
                <td className="py-3 px-6">{producto.Proveedor ? producto.Proveedor.nombre : 'N/A'}</td>
                <td className="py-3 px-6">{formatCurrency(producto.cantidad * producto.precio)}</td>
                <td className="py-3 px-6 text-center">
                  <button
                    onClick={() => handleEdit(producto)}
                    className="text-yellow-500 hover:text-yellow-600">
                    <i className="fa fa-pencil"></i> Editar
                  </button>
                  <button
                    onClick={() => handleDelete(producto.id)}
                    className="text-red-500 hover:text-red-600 ml-4">
                    <i className="fa fa-trash"></i> Eliminar
                  </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default GestionInventario;

Lo que ya he intentado:
He intentado actualizar la lista de productos tras la actualización, pero el nombre del proveedor sigue apareciendo como "N/A" de manera temporal.
He verificado la API y me agrega correctamente el nombre de proveedor más sin embargo no actualiza en el front end
¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema para que el nombre del proveedor se actualice correctamente sin tener que recargar la página?
Gracias de antemano.

Describe de forma mas detallada el proceso del select, cuando vas a editar aparecen las casillas de edición cada una con el valor a editar, luego cuando das click en la casilla de nombre de proveedor  (que parece ser el select) para intentar actualizarla el valor seleccionado cambia a N/A, ¿Es así el proceso?

Efectivamente es así el proceso sólo que para que se actualice correctamente tengo que recargar la página digamos que aparece N/A Las demás aparecen en blanco es un error lógico Pero cuando le doy en recargar la página el nombre del proveedor se actualiza correctamente.

He intentado actualizar la lista de productos tras la actualización Señala la parte del código donde estas haciendo esto, se debe de tener la información del registro en cada render para poder rellenar los campos con sus valores correspondientes en caso de solicitar la actualización del mismo.
